# Populating null Column's Value based on Previous value of another column

Tags: sql, oracle

```
--------------------------------------
code      Start DT   End date  Status
--------------------------------------
Y68 25/OCT/11   25/OCT/11   ADM_CHECKD
Y68 25/OCT/11   25/OCT/11   SATISFIED
Y68 25/OCT/11   25/OCT/11   SATISFIED
Y68 25/OCT/11   31/OCT/11   SATISFIED
Y68         SATISFIED
```

My requirement is, if the last row's start date is null it should have value 31/oct/11. That is previous row's end date value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How about getting the max end date and setting that?

Comment: Do you want to populate the table, or populate the column in a select query?

Comment: When you say "previous row" you are implying there is an order to the data. Are you ordering by `End Date` or by `Start DT` or other column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your intention by prior row is to get the last row ordered by end date for that came code, you can use:

```
SQL> select code,
  2         nvl(start_dt, lag(end_dt, 1) over (partition by code order by end_dt)) start_dt,
  3         end_dt, status
  4    from data
  5   order by start_dt;

COD START_DT  END_DT    STATUS
--- --------- --------- ----------
Y68 28-FEB-13 01-MAR-13 ADM_CHECKD
Y68 01-MAR-13 02-MAR-13 SATISFIED
Y68 02-MAR-13 03-MAR-13 SATISFIED
Y68 03-MAR-13 04-MAR-13 SATISFIED
Y68 04-MAR-13           SATISFIED
```

eg:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/abe8f/1